# SQL query concatenation to create file path

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to create a file path from 3 columns in a SQL query. This will be utilized in a file once everything is completed. I have tried using CONCAT and string methods for the columns but no luck. The query is provided below.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.TBIndexData.DocGroup, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index1 AS Title, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index2 AS Meeting_Date, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index3 AS Meeting_Number,
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index4 AS Meeting_Type, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index5 AS Doc_Name, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index6 AS Doc_Type,
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index7 AS Meeting_Page, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index8 AS Notes, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index9 AS TBUser, 
    dbo.TBIndexData.Index10 AS Date_Scanned, 
    CONCAT (dbo.TBPrimary.FileDir + '\' + dbo.TBPrimary.TimsFileID + '.' + dbo.TBPrimary.FileExtension) AS FilePath
FROM 
    dbo.TBIndexData
JOIN 
    dbo.TBPrimary ON dbo.TBIndexData.DocGroup = dbo.TBPrimary.DocGroup
```

Comment: `CONCAT` is SQL Server 2012. And doesn't have that syntax. What version are you actually on? 2008 per the tag?

Comment: dbo.TBPrimary.FileDir + '\' + dbo.TBPrimary.TimsFileID + '.' + dbo.TBPrimary.FileExtension AS FilePath

Comment: @IanKenney - Though if `TimsFileID` is numeric you need a cast.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am using SQL 2008 as per the tag. Why is CONCAT not available? So use CAST, not CONCAT since the column TimsFileID is always numeric?

Comment: Because it isn't implemented as a recognized function until SQL Server 2012. You need to use `+` and `CAST` any non string components yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you need something like

```
SELECT I.DocGroup,
       I.Index1  AS Title,
       I.Index2  AS Meeting_Date,
       I.Index3  AS Meeting_Number,
       I.Index4  AS Meeting_Type,
       I.Index5  AS Doc_Name,
       I.Index6  AS Doc_Type,
       I.Index7  AS Meeting_Page,
       I.Index8  AS Notes,
       I.Index9  AS TBUser,
       I.Index10 AS Date_Scanned, 
       P.FileDir + '\' + CAST(P.TimsFileID AS VARCHAR(10)) + 
            '.' + P.FileExtension AS FilePath
FROM   dbo.TBIndexData I
       JOIN dbo.TBPrimary P
         ON I.DocGroup = P.DocGroup
```

You shouldn't use `schemaname.tablename` in the `SELECT` list. This is [not officially supported grammar](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx). Just use `tablename` or give an alias.

(Using two part names there can lead to confusing errors if calling properties of columns of CLR datatypes)

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. I should of cleaned that up before posting because I was in AQT not using a defined table but running overall queries. Going to put myself in programmer's timeout.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use CONCAT with commas

`CONCAT (dbo.TBPrimary.FileDir, '\', dbo.TBPrimary.TimsFileID, '.', bo.TBPrimary.FileExtension) AS FilePath`

Comment: **No** - `CONCAT` is **not** available in the 2008 version of SQL Server - it's a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** and newer

Comment: Maybe this link will be helpfull? http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/310086/How-to-concatenate-two-columns-in-SQL-server-2008